# WSO2ESB how can change DB credentials within DBReport mediation deployed via car file

Tags: wso2-esb

```
  <dbreport>
    <connection>
        <pool>
            <password>lms!@#$</password>
            <user>lms-rwe</user>
            <property name="testonborrow" value="true"/>
            <url>jdbc:sqlserver://10.0.200.112\xyz;databaseName=vu450_dev_5_2</url>
            <property name="maxwait" value="60000"/>
            <property name="maxactive" value="80"/>
            <driver>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver>
        </pool>
    </connection>
```

Above code is deployed via car file in the QA WSO2ESB environment .
After successful testing we want to move in the UAT environment and want to change the DB userid,password and url.
when we edited this sequence the pop up appears

```
The changes will not persist to the CAPP after restart or redeploy. Do you want to Edit?
```

we performed edit but when we restart esb changes discarded.

Please guide how can i persist DB credentials in the mediator.

Comment: You could define a dataSource and refer it in dbreport config.

Answer (score 0):

When you restarted the ESB, artifacts are redeployed  from the CAPP, So editing the artifacts using management console only persist changes till restarting the server.

As the Jean commented, carbon data source is a better option. [Follow this link.](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB403/Adding+a+Data+Source)

Otherwise you have to edit the CAPP using developer studio and recreate the CAPP with changes which are relevant to the UAT environment.

Comment: Thanks Jean-Michel and Krishan.

Comment: I have created Data Service Project using Developer Studio

Comment: <data name="lms" serviceNamespace="" serviceGroup="">
    <description/>
    <config id="1">
        <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.user">lms-rwe</property>
        <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.password">lms!@#$</property>
        <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.protocol">jdbc:sqlserver://10.0.100.112\lms:1433/databaseName=vu360_dev_5_2</property>
        <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.driver">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
    </config>
</data>

Comment: How can i create car file for this data service project